# android USB debugging disappeared and not working anymore

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, adb

I was working on my project using my own device ( LG Optimus G E975 , android 4.4.2) on ubuntu 12.04, and everything was going fine, eclipse could detect the device and I could easily debug on device. Suddenly the debugging icon in status bar was gone and the only thing it now shows is the charging icon, the usb debugging is turned on in developer options. when I connect my phone to laptop and using

```
adb devices
```

it doesn't find any device. I've tried pluging the device to laptop many times and still the same. what could possibly go wrong??

Comment: Try to run `adb kill-server && adb start-server` and then restart Eclipse

Comment: It did not solve it, the phone still shows the charge only icon, I've tried connecting it to other computers but the usb debugging icon doesn't show up at all

Comment: @arashmoeen : try shutting down your device! sometimes works

Comment: @Arash It did not work, but thanks for the tip

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It happens some times when we frequently use the real device for debugging purpose, it's not your devices problem, it is because of USB chord, try using a different **USB chord**, it will start work again.

Comment: I've changed the cable and it didn't solve the problem, still can't get the device to be in usb debugging

Comment: In my case it was the cable

Answer (score 1):

Ok here's how I fixed it. I simply changed the USB that I was using, my laptop has 3 USB slots and 2 of them didn't respond well to USB debugging but the 3rd one worked, although I'm using another USB cable than the one I was using at the time O posted this question, but the new cable didn't work until I changed the USB slot.

Comment: I had exactly same problem with my Nexus tablet vs Mac.. First i could have seen the device without problem, then it suddenly stopped. My Mac has two USB ports, i tried to switch it from one to another, but it didnt help. Then i connected it to another computer (PC), there the debug icon appeared instantly, then i was again connecting to Mac to one port and second, and at the same time i was toggling "enable USB debuging in tablet settings" and it started working again.. dont know if PC succesful connection has kickstarted it, or it is enough just switch ports on original problematic "pc"

Answer (score 0):

You should execute these commands

adb kill-server

adb start-server

then unplug your usb cable and plugin again., it will start working again.,

you can check by using command

adb devices